# Error -1 when attempting to accept a non-blocking OpenSSL socket. Accepting twice with a delay works

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

I'm writing a simple http server in C, I added some OpenSSL around it to support secure connections and it works great with blocking sockets.

However if I switch to non-blocking sockets, the SSL_accept(ssl) always returns -1 on the first attempt, even if I add a time delay before it.

I originally assumed it may have something to do with the socket not ready for reads/writes but that doesn't seem to be the case as a delay of even 150ms had the same behavior.

However, if I execute SSL_accept(ssl) then issue a short 50ms delay and retry SSL_accept(ssl), I get a successful SSL connection each time. Sending and receiving encrypted traffic works just as expected.

I'm not using socket select, I'm simply polling sockets for connect/recv/send.

Why is this? Am I missing a required call for non-blocking accepts?

Below is the snippet I've added to my code to mitigate this behavior.

```
    int sslfail = SSL_accept(ssl);
    #if NONBLOCKINGIO
    // Perculiar issue where non-blocking sockets require 2 accept attempts with a brief delay betweek them to avoid error.
    usleep(50 * 1000);
    sslfail = SSL_accept(ssl);
    #endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ssl_accept man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_accept):

> If the underlying BIO is non-blocking, SSL_accept() will also return
> when the underlying BIO could not satisfy the needs of SSL_accept() to
> continue the handshake, indicating the problem by the return value -1.
> In this case a call to SSL_get_error() with the return value of
> SSL_accept() will yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE .
> The calling process then must repeat the call after taking appropriate
> action to satisfy the needs of SSL_accept(). The action depends on the
> underlying BIO . When using a non-blocking socket, nothing is to be
> done, but select() can be used to check for the required condition.
> When using a buffering BIO , like a BIO pair, data must be written
> into or retrieved out of the BIO before being able to continue.

Comment: Indeed, it appears SSL_get_error tells me I have SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ. And the retry satisfies it. I'll add some proper logic to handle this. Thank you!

Comment: It is not the retry itself that makes it succeed. It is the fact that you have to wait long enough for the client to send data so the handshake has something to read. You may have to call `SSL_accept()` many times before it finally succeeds, so call it in a loop until either success is reported, or a fatal error is reported. `SSL_ERROR_WANT_(READ|WRITE)` are not fatal errors.